# Changing function arguments in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I want to remove the command line arguments from the following code and give arguments through code

```
# Handle arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--target',  required=True)
parser.add_argument('--policy', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--name', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--insecure', action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('--ca_bundle')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Log in
scan = rest.Scanner(url=_url, login=login, password=password, insecure=args.insecure, ca_bundle=args.ca_bundle)

# Set policy that should be used
scan.policy_set(name=args.policy)
```

I want to convert the code so that I can pass arguments from code instead of command line. Some thing like this

```
a=target
b=policyname
c=scan_name
d=xyz
args=(a,b,c,d)
scan = rest.Scanner(url=_url, login=login, password=password, insecure=args.d, ca_bundle=args.ca_bundle)

scan.policy_set=(name=args.b)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Just do as you wrote? instead of touble for `args` use `dict` though.

Comment: Well it's pretty darn explicit that command line args are expected... You don't need the `parser` object at all if you don't want to use that interface. Just wrap it in a function instead.

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass the parameters directly.

```
scan = rest.Scanner(url=a,password=b,insecure=true,.....)
```